# Insert statement with nested Select and inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server

For a clock machine.

This will automatically set a clock record in the table at midnight for people who forgot to clock out in the evening. I want it to insert a clock record the same as their clock in time

Employee table has the usual, employeeID, employeeName, ClockTypeID
ClockTypeID is a quick reference for the employees current status (working (1) or not working (2))
Clock Table has ClockID, ClockTypeID, EmployeeID, ClockDate, ClockTime

at the moment I have (and what I want it to do)

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Clock(EmployeeID, ClockTypeID, ClockDate, ClockTime)
        SELECT EmployeeID, 2, getdate(), [Mininum clock time for current day for current employee]
        FROM Employee
        WHERE employee.ClockTypeID <> 2;
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Bit more info

[image: Clock Table Data]
[image: Employee Table Data]

I want to, when the query is run in the evening; insert a row into the clock table for each of the employees who has the ClockTypeID of '1' (indicating they are still clocked In)
The row I want to insert, I want the date to be the current date and the time to be the time of the first clock in (clocktypeID 1) of that day. 
This will end with their clock-in time and date being the same as their clock-out time and date. Meaning the system will say they have worked 0 hours for that day which should be a flag to their superiors so they can manually correct it.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help explain what you want to do.

Comment: Have added some more information, hopefully that's enough!

Answer (score 0):

Your description suggests something like this:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Clock(EmployeeID, ClockTypeID, ClockDate, ClockTime)
    SELECT EmployeeID, 2, CAST(getdate() as DATE), min(clocktime)
    FROM Employee
    GROUP BY EmployeeId, CAST(getdate() as DATE)
    HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN ClockTypeID = 1 THEN 1
                    WHEN ClockTypeId = 2 THEN -1
                    ELSE 0
               END) > 0;
```